# Cop gets beat up at a party and I ran so

Tags: police

If people get into a scuffle and at a small party and a cop friend is around and he gets beat up and knocked cold out, when he awakes can he legally arrest anyone that was there before but not after he woke up?

I'm wondering in a situation like this, what should occur? How can you be protected if you are an assumed violator but I did not touch anyone (I just cut out).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most jurisdictions a peace officer can arrest anyone they have:

1. a warrant to arrest
2. probable cause to arrest, that is, a reasonable belief that that person has committed a crime

They (and others) will conduct investigations to determine if they believe they can secure a conviction. If they do they will lay charges and justice will steer it's majestic course to conviction or acquittal.